# fix an almost working re.search process

Tags: regex, python-3.x

i'm just trying to know if a string from a table A (eg. a list A) "Crude protein (min.)" is in a string of string like `"Crude protein,protein,Protein,Protein    (crude),Crude protein (min.)"`from a table B (e.G a list B) But in fact  table B is built in order to contain every string from table A.

That's how it works :

```
for i in  range(0,len(B)):
  for j in range(0,len(A)):
      if re.search(re.escape(A[j][0]),B[i][0]) : 
          print("FOUND",A[j][0],"IN",B[i][0])
```

It works well for some of them :

```
FOUND Angelica root IN Angelica root
FOUND Arginine IN Arginine
FOUND Biotin IN Biotin
FOUND Calcium (min.) IN Calcium,Calcium (min.)
FOUND Calcium: Phosphorus Ratio IN Calcium: Phosphorus Ratio
```

But for some of them, it shouldn't be :

```
FOUND Chloride IN Chloride glucosamine
```

That's too much. The previous :

```
FOUND Chloride IN Chloride
```

was enough.

Another example :

```
FOUND Methionline-Cysteine IN Methionine Cystine,Methionline-Cysteine,Methionine-Cysteine
FOUND Methionine IN Methionine Cystine,Methionline-Cysteine,Methionine-Cysteine
```

The second output is wrong ! I would like it not to find that second one.

How can i manage to do that with `regex` ? I feel that there is a lack of criteria somewhere but I don't understand really deeply how it works yet. 
Or maybe is there another, maybe re-built table B otherwise ?

Comment: Are you trying to find strings that contain sth, but are not equal to sth? `if A[j][0].find(B[i][0]) > -1 and A[j][0] != B[i][0]:`?

Comment: Why are you using regex at all if you escape all regex operators? Just use simple  string search, it's faster, easier to write, and easier to read.

Comment: Actually i thought regex was the necessary way to deal with this matter. Apparently not. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex here. You can split the second value into a list and check if the first item is contained in the list:

```
for i in  range(0, len(B)):
    for j in range(0, len(A)):
        if A[j][0] in B[i][0].split(','):
            print("FOUND", A[j][0], "IN", B[i][0])
```

**EDIT:**

To clear up the confusion surrounding the `in` statement, here is an example:

```
needle = "Methionine"
haystack = ["Methionine Cystine", "Methionline-Cysteine", "Methionine-Cysteine"]

needle in haystack  # returns False
```

The above code compares the needle against every item in the haystack, and returns True if one of the items matches (`==`). Since the string "Methionine" does not match "Methionine Cystine" using `==`, nor does it match any of the other strings in the haystack list, the `in` statement returns `False`.

Comment: You can make this a lot faster by iterating over `(set(b[0].split(',')) for b in B)` instead.

Comment: Thanks really! It works actually on the few test i've made. But for me it shouldn't. Indeed, even if you split, your condition test if `Methionine` from the "another exemple" is in `Methionine Cystine` and then in `Methionline-Cysteine`. It should say true because indeed, the `str` `Methionine` is in `Methionine Cystine`. It's like the splitting create also group. Why is that so ? In addition if i test `if "methionine" in "methionine cysteine" : print("a")` in a shell : it gives a out. Why are those situation different ?

Comment: The `split` creates a list of strings that looks like this: ["Methionine Cystine", "Methionline-Cysteine", Methionine-Cysteine"]. The `if` statement then compares the string "Methionine" against each item in this list. The string comparison "Methionine" == "Methionine Cystine" returns false, because the strings are not the same.

Comment: By your comment, do you mean this answer works, or does not work?

Comment: In response to your comment edit: the `if` statement is not making the comparison you wrote. Instead it is comparing `if "Methionine" in ["Methionine Cysteine", "Methio..."]: print("a")`. The `split` function is returning a list of strings.

Comment: The code works fine ! But i still don't understand. You're talking about a `==` comparison. Here were a doing a `if in`.

Comment: I understand the split process. And then it tests if : for each element in the created list, `methionine`is contained in it :  Is `methionine`  in `methionine cysteine` => YES. Is `methionine == methionine cysteine` => Definitely NO ! So here we are using `in`and for reasons i don't understand (but a reason which makes me happy because it's what i wanted) it doesn't return `true` for : is `methionine` in `methionine cysteine`. There is something i miss.

Comment: I have edited the answer with an additional example.

Comment: I would suggest reading up on examples of using the `in` statement with lists. If the answer works for you, please mark it accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Perfectly clear with your edit. I thank you for those answers.